# What is a graph topology(CS) called in mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In computer science we refer to the "shape" of a graph as the graph's topology. [Here is an example](https://beginnersbook.com/2019/03/computer-network-topology-mesh-star-bus-ring-and-hybrid/) of this usage.

In computer science a graph topology `T` is a a set of unlabled graphs which all share a given property or set of properties. A graph `A` has topology `T` if an isomorphism exists between `A` and one of the graphs in `T`.

I am, however, aware of the fact that mathematicians DO NOT use the word topology in this way. Is there another word that graph theorists use?

Comment: Graph, directed graph, undirected graph, weighted graph.   Topology is a complete misnomer.  A useful description would be shape.

Comment: @WilliamElliot it is not a misnomer, it is merely a word used differently in a different field of study. Just as it is not a misnomer to refer to a chart as a graph outside of discrete mathematics ;) . We are NOT referring to the distinctions between directed, undirected and weighted graphs (those are types of graphs). I we are referring to the shapes of the graphs, but is the word "shape" used in mathematics?

Comment: "Shape" doesn't seem right to me, because a star and a decagon are different shapes but are isomorphic when viewed as graphs. Topologies are the same, however, across all deformations.

Comment: I would not worry. "Network topology" is a well established term. Especially graph theorists will have no problem with that.